# WPF Make Interactive Charts

Tags: c#, wpf, data-visualization

I'm using **System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit** for charts in my [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application.
The code for chart is:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart>
                        <!-- Volume -->
                        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries
                            Title="Volume (M)"
                            ItemsSource="{StaticResource StockDataCollection}"
                            IndependentValuePath="Date"
                            DependentValuePath="Volume"/>
                        <!-- Price -->
                        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries
                            Title="Price ($)"
                            ItemsSource="{StaticResource StockDataCollection}"
                            IndependentValuePath="Date"
                            DependentValuePath="Price"/>
                        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                            <!-- Axis for custom range -->
                            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis
                                Orientation="Y"
                                Minimum="0"
                                Maximum="100"
                                ShowGridLines="True"/>
                            <!-- Axis for custom labels -->
                            <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis
                                Orientation="X">
                                <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxisLabel">
                                        <Setter Property="StringFormat" Value="{}{0:MMM d}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                            </chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis>
                        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

I want the user be able to click line series at any point and drag it to up or down and so the Value will be changed ?
This is like a two way data binding but I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this library

http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#visual-editing-of-data

Comment: this is very nice however I ended up doing the interactive chart myself and the software is long time working now , but I'm going to accept your answer because looks like the best answer however a bit late !!

Answer (score 2):

The WPF Toolkit chart control doesn't have any code to handle mouse dragging, so you'll have to write it yourself.

You should be able to subclass `LineDataPoint` to add dragging functionality, then subclass `LineSeries` and override `CreateDataPoint()`to create your custom LineDataPoint items.

In this case, your `ItemsSource` would not be an IEnumerable of values (eg `IEnumerable<decimal>`), but rather of value holder objects (eg `IEnumerable<MyValueObject>`).  The value holder objects would have a property that can be used to retrieve or set the value at that point, Allowing the value to be updated by setting `DependentValueBinding` to a `TwoWay` binding to your property.  You may be able to reuse existing objects in your application rather than creating a value holder object specifically for this purpose.